# What is the quickest way to export an entire database locally?

Tags: mysql

Don't need to care about anything using the database of course since it's on my local computer.

Doesn't need to be compressed. Speed is what I am after, but it should work of course later if I import it again.

It's a magento (1) db if that matters.

InnoDB.

Comment: Because the database binary file structure (innodb) are the same for the most MySQL versions you could try copy the files in the data directory from the remote into the local data directory .  But be warned it could **corrupt** the files so be sure you have backups

Comment: safer option would be using [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) to export and to import the [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) client program